# Sending context information to chatbot

Tags: botframework

While launching a web chat bot from a portal (through iframe), is it possible to send the details of the logged in user (who has already logged into the portal) to the bot and save it in the bot state so it can retrieved inside the bot code to do some customization or apply custom logic based on the user details. User details can include their name, date of birth, gender etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web app and bot can exchange information "behind the scenes" (i.e., invisible to the end-user) by exchanging activities of **type** `event`. An activity with type `event` will not be displayed by clients such as Web Chat, so the end user won't see any evidence of the communication. This type of communication between client and bot is sometimes referred to as the "backchannel mechanism."

For an example of how this is done, check out Ryan Volum's [backchannel sample bot](https://github.com/ryanvolum/backChannelBot).

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.